# How to scale histogram bar heights in matplotlib / seaborn?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

My dataset is a numpy array of size (m, 1) and I need 2 plots: a) one of the whole data normalized (probability) b) one of a subset of the dataset keeping the same normalization as before.

The problem is that in case b) the normalization options provided by matplotlib and seaborn only "see" the subset so they cannot normalize based on the whole data.

Essentially what I want to do is:

```
bar_height = bar_count / m
```

Sample data:

```
array([[-0.00996642],
       [ 0.00407526],
       [ 0.00547561],
       ...,
       [ 0.05205999],
       [ 0.00224144],
       [ 0.01201942]])
```

Comment: [`sns.histplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot) has a parameter `stat=`: `{“count”, “frequency”, “density”, “probability”}`

Comment: I know. The problem is that I need to plot B with the "probability" of A.
B is a subset of A

Comment: So I need to manually calculate the bins, bar_widths, bar_heights and plot them in a bar plot.
I was wondering if there is a bar scaling option in the histogram plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.histogram()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to calculate the histogram and then draw the bars with [`plt.bar()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar) :

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set()
m = 200
samples = np.random.rand(1000)
hist_values, bin_edges = np.histogram(samples)
plt.bar(x=bin_edges[:-1], height=hist_values / m, width=np.diff(bin_edges), align='edge')
plt.show()
```